# Spring-boot multi-module configuration and test isolation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I 'm working on an application splitted in maven modules as follows :

- myApp-parent

  - framework
  - module1

    - persistence
    - service
  - module2

    - persistence
    - service

**First part : the persistence layer**

For the module1/persistence, the sources are located in a package `org.company.myApp.module1.persistence` and I have a the following configuration class :

```
package org.company.myApp.module1.persistence;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.config.EnableLdapRepositories;

import org.company.myApp.framework.FrameworkConfiguration;

@Configuration
@Import(FrameworkConfiguration.class)
@EntityScan
@ComponentScan
@EnableLdapRepositories("org.company.myApp.module1.persistence.ldap")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.company.myApp.module1.persistence.db")
public class Module1PersistenceConfiguration {

}
```

**First question** : I used `@Configuration` here. I didn't put `@SpringBootApplication` because the persistence is not a standalone application but just a kind of a library. Nevertheless, should I use `@SpringBootConfiguration` here instead of `@Configuration`?

It looks like `@SpringBootConfiguration` is just an alias of `@Configuration` but despite the many articles I read it is still unclear to me.

The documentation states :

> Indicates that a class provides Spring Boot application @Configuration. Can be used as an alternative to the Spring's standard @Configuration annotation so that configuration can be found automatically (for example in tests).
>
> Application should only ever include one @SpringBootConfiguration and most idiomatic Spring Boot applications will inherit it from @SpringBootApplication.

As the final application with all modules would contain multiple `@SpringBootConfiguration`, I went for the simple `@Configuration`.

**Second part : the persistence layer tests**

The test sources are in the same package (under `src/test/java` of course) and I made a test specific configuration class :

```
package org.company.myApp.module1.persistence;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.LdapProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Module1PersistenceTestConfiguration extends Module1PersistenceConfiguration {

}
```

The `extends Module1PersistenceConfiguration` seems useless here, because as the both classes are in the same package, the scan will detect and load the main configuration.

The `@SpringBootApplication` allows me to load the Spring context as my tests with `@SpringBootTest` detect this class.

**Second question :** If I annotated the main configuration with `@SpringBootConfiguration`, the `Module1PersistenceTestConfiguration` would have been useless ? What is the correct approach here ?

**Third part : the service layer**

The configuration class :

```
package org.company.myApp.module1.service;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import org.company.myApp.module1.persistence.Module1PersistenceConfiguration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@Import(Module1PersistenceConfiguration.class)
public class Module1ServiceConfiguration {

}
```

As the service layer and the persistence layer do not have the same package, I use the `@Import(Module1PersistenceConfiguration.class)` to trigger the scan of the persistence layer.

**Third question :** Although I feel comfortable with this, maybe there is a better alternative ? The service layer should be aware of the persistence layer and do the full scan by adding the according `basePackages` property to the `@ComponentScan` ?

**Final part : the service layer tests**

This is the part where I'm struggling with.
I would like to test the service layer by mocking the persistence layer and the only way I manage to do this is by adding a test configuration class which excludes the main configuration class to prevent spring from trying to load the persistence layer (due to the `@Import` in the main configuration) and failing because there is not datasource configuration in the properties (the persistence tests resources contain an application.properties in order to use an H2 embedded database and an unboundid embedded LDAP) :

```
package org.company.myApp.module1.service;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = Module1ServiceConfiguration.class))
public class Module1ServiceTestConfiguration {

}
```

Moreover, I'm forced to mock all beans which are coming from the persistence layer for every single tests.

**Final question :** What would be the correct way to achieve this ?
An answer could be : do unit testing on your service or do integration testing which includes the persistence layer but your semi-integration tests don't make any sense ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't asked, but in this answer I have assumed you are talking about maven modules and not about java modules. If you are talking about Java modules, still the majority holds true, but maybe not everything.

Your have a lot of questions, and I am not sure I can answer them all, but I can share with you my strategy for controlling the context of my SpringBootTest.

Usually I only write SpringBootTests when there is some specific configuration that I want to check is properly loaded, or for testing Controllers or Clients. For anything else I write regular unit tests (yes also, when they are services). Keep the test context small and local to the class you want to test. Only load into the context those beans that you really need for that particular test. Test contexts can become a hell to maintain if you don't keep them under control. Do not create one massive TestConfiguration. Because in some cases some beans needs to be mocked, while in other cases you don't want to mock them. This can become an absolute nightmare

Generally my SpringBootTests are set up as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyService.class)
@Import(MyServiceTestConfiguration.class)
class MyServiceTest {
   // test logic
}

@TestConfiguration
class MyServiceTestConfiguration.class {

    @MockBean
    BeanINeedMocked beanINeedMocked;
    // or whatever other strategy you want to use to create a mocked bean
}
```

By defining classes under @SpringBootTest, it will not look for an @SpringBootApplication on the class path. When the test is loaded, Spring context will load the mentioned class (and I believe any other Bean in the same package). If you need any other non mocked beans to get the application context to load, include them in the @SpringBootTest(classes = {MyService.class, WhatEverOtherBeanYouNeed.class} But only load what you need to test whatever you want to test!

This way you don't need a OneTestConfigurationToRuleThemAll.class for you all your springboottests in your application, and you don't have 3000 tests failing whenever you add a new spring bean to your application.

Two final notes:
Make sure your SpringBootApplication class is on the root of your application (the root path that is shared by all modules). This way you never have to use @ComponentScan or anything like that. As long as all @Configuration, @Service, @Component have the complete path of where the SpringBootApplication is on, all will be scanned and loaded automatically.

If you do this correctly, and all your maven modules are wired correctly, you will not have to import configuration from other modules. As long as the module has a dependency on the module it needs spring beans from, it should be autowired out of the box.

Also, if you use @SpringBootApplication, I would not use @SpringBootConfiguration anywhere but just stick to @Configuration.

Comment: I tried the nested `@TestConfiguration` approach but as far as I remember it didn't fully solved my problems. Could you please provide a simple working example ?

Comment: I basically already did, all my tests look like the above example. Make sure you add the Class you want to test as a class to the SpringBootTest annotation, otherwise it will scan the classpath upward for a SpringBootApplication annotation and load more context then you want. There are often small things, specific to your situation that prevent from it working straight away that you need to figure out. Once you get the hang of this, you can setup any test. Please try it out one class at a time, and come back with specific problems to solve.

Comment: Also make sure you comply to the other notes about properly setting up and wiring your spring boot application. Once you start using component scan or importing configurations all over the place, it can become an entangled mess that might make basic setups like a spring boot test fail.

Comment: Why do you want to load a Spring context for unit testing ? If I need to unit test a class, I simply use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and play with `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`. Actually I think I'm looking for a feature doing something like : "Mock all unsatisfied dependency in my spring context and let me autowire the mocks in my test class so I can define their behaviour".

Comment: Regarding the spring context, you mean that the good practice is to set the configuration only in the application module ? Let's say I have a module rest-controller exposing some services through a REST API, it should have a `@SpringBootApplication` scanning all the module it depends on ? And all the other modules should not have `@Configuration` class ?

Comment: No,the others can have Configuration classes, but you don't have to manually scan or import those with CompentScan or Import if the project is setup correctly. Make sure your spring boot application is on the root path, and that modules have dependencies on the modules they need, then everything is wired properly without manual actions. (module inter-dependencies should also be one directional though!)